# fopen() always return NULL when I'm trying to read a txt file

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, fopen

When I'm trying to read a txt file with fopen(), it always return NULL. How can I fix that?

[image: Problem code.]

Comment: i also tried with

Comment: Wrong working dirrctory or path name or file permissions

Comment: i also tried with "C:\\ass2\\markassignment1.txt", "C:/ass2/markassignment1.txt" and it still doesnt work

Comment: Stop guessing - use `perror` to print out the error message!

Comment: most likely, this path: `C:/ass2/....` should start with: `C:/class2/.....`

Answer (score 0):

Use double slashes:

"C:\Documents and Settings\juegos psps.txt"

Since they are must be enclosed with double quotes and \ is a special character hence we must perform an escape sequence.